# Foreach only taking the first value from Array

Tags: php, loops, foreach, submit

I have the following code:

```
         $referrals = inputFilter($_POST['referralsIds']);
         $array =explode(",",$referrals);

         foreach($array as $key=>$value):

            /
            $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE upline='".$userdata['id']."' AND id='$value'");
            $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($s);

            if($num_rows==0)
                return 2;

        // No error found and the update was succesful - Return success!            
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET upline='' WHERE id='$value'");
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rbalance=rbalance-".$sdata['direct_delete_fee'].", direct_referrals=direct_referrals-1 WHERE username='".$userdata['username']."'");

            return 100; 

         endforeach;
```

The $referrals variable is posting two values (10,11).But when I put it in a foreach loop, it will only run the query with the first value (10). How to do so it run through ALL values submitted?

Thanks.

Comment: your return statements will exit the loop when its run the first time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `return 100` inside your for loop. It's terminating the loop on its first iteration.

`return` statements terminate the enclosing function. If you need to return multiple results, consider pushing them onto an array and then returning the array once you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You have code returning before the end of your for each

```
     return 100; //HERE
 endforeach;
```

You probably want:

```
endforeach;
return 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have two values, then you explode it ? :O But i think you meant $array.

You have `return 100` which will return from the function, and as well from foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 100 from whatever function you're in on the first iteration of the loop. returning will cause the loop to stop immediately.